# How to insert your Google Analytics tracking code in your Strikingly website with a free account?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, self-tracking-entities

Given:

1. website is ready on Strikingly
2. free account
3. no access to my code

Question:

- how to insert my tracking code? can i use a tool and hide the code in it?

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the code you cant add the Google Analytics tracker.  Unless Strikingly has some kind of addon for it.  I would contact Strikingly.